# loading an external html with it's own unique css

Tags: php, html

I've been asked to look into an existing website. The way it works now, they have one main root html file with multiple iframes in it linking to external htmls. Now they like to figure out if there's any other alternatives to Iframes because it's slowing down their page.

So I've tested using php includes and jquery .load function. It sort of works but I have to dig down each page and set the path to images/css/js from the root folder. To make it worse some of the css are overlapping each other. Is there a way to load external htmls but keep their own unique css files contained within themselves?

Original code using Iframes. I need to replace the Iframe with an alternative:

```
<div class = "container" style = "margin-top: 2%;">
            <iframe src="home-slide/index.html" height="100%" width="100%" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="info">
</div>
```

I hope that made sense. Not sure if this question has been asked before but I'm not sure what keywords to put in.

Comment: could you please share some sample code?

Comment: DO NOT use include() as PHP will run the file as if it was a PHP file, so if it's an untrusted file from another site the site's contents if it contains PHP code will run on your server and is a huge security risk. I suggest using file_get_contents() as it will get the contents as plain-text HTML source.

Comment: Cross-site content or same site?

Comment: @Ummar I put some original code in the post. I'd share everything but like I said, I've been asked to look at their website to avoid using Iframes. It's a bit of a mess at the moment where every external links have their own separate folder with it's own css.

Comment: @Cryptic So far all ther external htmls are pretty much within the same sub-folders. I've never used php includes to load an external html from another website.

Comment: Well, I believe the simplest way is to either keep on using frames, or re-structure your site.

Comment: @Alvin Wong That's what I have in mind. Re-Structuring the website would take ages. I have to make sure all css work together probably have to write something from scratch. Right now it looks like the original designer/coder took a lot of sample websites with plugins and jumble them up together. Very messy. The IFrame works fine, but all the content must dynamically scale to the browser window. And one of the pages uses a colorbox lightbox. In Firefox, i need to refresh that page so the iframe loads the lightbox properly :P Thanks for the comment btw.

Comment: You are basically stuck with iframes.  You can use PHP, AJAX or another method to load the external HTML content into your page, but you cannot localize CSS files to specific areas within the document - you will have to merge and optimize the CSS files (and probably also some of the HTML classes and IDs) in order to get away from frames.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible. Stylesheets as a whole are applied on a browsing context, meaning the entire frame, or the 'superframe' that is the entire window. As such the only way to separate blocks of content that have conflicting stylesheets is to use the frames mechanism.

Your question sort of boils down to *"I've been asked to hammer a nail in the wall, but I can't use a hammer, nor a nail"*. If you have a valid solution, use it.